# Unable to simulate onclick javascript inside <span> tag using Selenium webdriver,python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to simulate onclick event at the following tag

span class="taLnk hvrIE6 tr165579546 moreLink ulBlueLinks" onclick="ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(2247);ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.expandReviews',event,this,'review_165579546', '1', 2247)">
More

This is used to see more text under this link.I am using selenium webdriver and python for simulating this event automatically for this webpage
 http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297586-d1154547-Reviews-Rainbow_International_Hotel-Hyderabad_Telangana.html this webpage.

could anyone pls share a code snippet inorder to actiavet this javascript event so that page loads up and I can see whole text under that link automatically...I tried using click() option of selenium webdriver but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297586-d1154547-Reviews-Rainbow_International_Hotel-Hyderabad_Telangana.html'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
li = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#PERSISTENT_TAB_HR .tabs_pers_content li:nth-child(2)')
li.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea that you may start with:

- iterate over all reviews on the page (div elements with `id` starting with `review_`)
- for every review, click on the `More` link *if it is present* (span with `moreLink` class name)
- after a small delay, get the full review text

Here's the implementation:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g297586-d1154547-Reviews-Rainbow_International_Hotel-Hyderabad_Telangana.html")

for review in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "review_")]'):
    try:
        more = WebDriverWait(review, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'moreLink')))
        if more.is_displayed():
            more.click()
            time.sleep(1)
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        pass

    full_review = review.find_element_by_class_name('dyn_full_review')
    print full_review.text
    print "----"
```

Prints (the output contains all text inside each review including username and date):

```
Mustufa W
1 review
“Horrible”
Reviewed August 15, 2014
I checked on price was high but cracked a deal
Poor hygiene in corridor & so in rooms. Washroom pipes were leaking. AC water dripping in washroom.
First I was given a room to which my surprise found window pane was missing after complaining room got changed.
They are cheating ppl only good thing abt hotel is the spot & is damn opposite Nilofer cafe which serves delicious tea,coffee & bakery products.
There is a guy named khwaja who was very helpful. Front @ reception guy was stupid..in one midnight , power went off & to my surprise they don't have power back up..
Stayed August 2014, traveled as a couple
Less
Was this review helpful?
Yes
Ask Mustufa W about Rainbow International Hotel
This review is the subjective opinion of a TripAdvisor member and not of TripAdvisor LLC.
----
mrravi4u
Bangalore, India
2 reviews
13 helpful votes
“Good Hotel”
Reviewed April 23, 2014
I stayed there 2 days i got good services. Rainbow Is good hotel in Hyderabad. there are very homely environment and hosting services was supper. it is also in center of hyderabad city so for convenience is is better place to stay.
Room Tip: Office Meeting
See more room tips
Stayed March 2014, traveled with friends
Value
Location
Sleep Quality
Rooms
Cleanliness
Service
Was this review helpful?
Yes
13
Ask mrravi4u about Rainbow International Hotel
This review is the subjective opinion of a TripAdvisor member and not of TripAdvisor LLC.
----
...
```

Hope that makes things more clear for you.